# fetching three values i.e RoomNumber,OccupantName and Building as a (list-group)popover format from a web api using jquery and ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm fetching  three values i.e  `RoomNumber`,`OccupantName` and `Building` as a popover format from a web api  using jquery and ajax but  the problem is while i'm fetching  the records from api according to RoomNumber  it shows the record based on  roomNumber but when i again click the button it again gives the same record.

So my ***question*** is how to restrict the filtration of data which is already fetched and present in the list-group and only show those record which are not exists.

I'm here by presenting my code for better clarification:(Please help me,thank you)

```
<pre>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <nav id="myNavmenu" class=" bg-primary navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas MySlide" role="navigation" style="background-color: #d9edf7; padding-top:10px;">
            <div class="input-group custom-search-form col-lg-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="txtRoomNo" placeholder="Enter room no." />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnsSearch">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             </button>
             </span> 
            </div><br/>

             <div class="panel panel-success" id="panelBody">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Room Details</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-body" style="height: 800px;">
                     <div class="list-group scroll-area" id="userList" style="height: 100%">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </nav>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="click" id="launchButton" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body" style="height:220px; margin-top:300px;">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
      </button>
    </form>
</pre>
```

```js
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>  



<script type="text/javascript">
     var isFirst = true;
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#demo").popover();
         $(".scroll-area").scrollspy();
         $("#btnsSearch").click(function () {
             if ($("#txtRoomNo").val().length != 0) {
                 ApiCall();
             }
             else {
                 $("#userList .list-group-item").remove();
                 return false;
             }
         });
         $("#txtRoomNo").keydown(function (event) {
             var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
             if (keyCode == "13") {
                 if ($("#txtRoomNo").val().length != 0) { ApiCall(); return false; }
                 else { $("#userList .list-group-item").remove(); return false; }
             }
         });

         $("#launchButton").click(function () {
             $("#txtRoomNo").val("");
             $("#userList .list-group-item").remove()
         })
     });//End of document.ready
     function ApiCall() {
         
         $.ajax({
             url: "https://wpsvc5.com/esawebapi/api/entities/getroomnolist",
             type: "get", //send it through get method
             data: { customerCode: "018", RoomNumber: $("#txtRoomNo").val() },
             success: function (response) {
                 if (response.length == 0) {
                     $("#userList .list-group-item").remove();
                     $("#userList").append('<li class=list-group-item id=NoData style=color:#d44950;font-weight:bold;>No Data Avaliable !!!</li>');
                 }
                 else {
                     $("#userList #NoData").remove();
                     for (var i = 0 ; i < response.length; i++) {
                         if (response[i].CurrentOccupant != "") {
                             $("#userList").append('<a  href="#" class=list-group-item active  data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html=true  style=color:#666666;font-weight:normal;>' + response[i].RoomNumber + '<br/>' + response[i].CurrentOccupant + '<br/>' + response[i].Building + '<br/></a>');
                         }
                         else {
                             $('#userList').append('<a href="#" class=list-group-item active data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html=true  style=color:#666666;font-weight:normal;>' + response[i].RoomNumber + '<br/>' + '<b style="color:blue;font-weight:normal">Vacant</b>' + '<br/>' + response[i].Building + '<br/></a>');
                         }
                         if (response[i].CurrentOccupant != "") {

                             if (isFirst==true) {
                                 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                                     placement: 'bottom',
                                     title: "Room Details",
                                     content: response[i].RoomNumber + '<br/>' + response[i].CurrentOccupant + ' <br/> ' + response[i].Building
                                 });
                                 isFirst = false;
                             }
                             else {
                                 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                                     placement: 'top',
                                     title: "Room Details",
                                     content: response[i].RoomNumber + ' <br/> ' + response[i].CurrentOccupant + ' <br/> ' + response[i].Building
                                 });
                             }
                         }


                         if (response[i].CurrentOccupant == "") {
                            
                             if (isFirst == true) {
                                 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                                     placement: 'bottom',
                                     title: "Room Details",
                                     content: response[i].RoomNumber + ' <br/> ' + '<b style="color:blue;font-weight:normal"> Vacant </b>' + ' <br/> ' + response[i].Building
                                 });
                                 isFirst = false;
                             }
                             else {
                                 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                                     placement: 'top',
                                     title: "Room Details",
                                     content: response[i].RoomNumber + ' <br/> ' + '<b style="color:blue;font-weight:normal"> Vacant </b>' + ' <br/> ' + response[i].Building
                                 });
                             }

                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });
     }
    </script>
```

```css
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/dist/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <link href="https://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/navmenu-push.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .scroll-area {
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .popover-title {
            color: #428bca;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .popover-content {
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <nav id="myNavmenu" class=" bg-primary navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas MySlide" role="navigation" style="background-color: #d9edf7; padding-top:10px;">
            <div class="input-group custom-search-form col-lg-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="txtRoomNo" placeholder="Enter room no." />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnsSearch">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             </button>
             </span> 
            </div><br/>

             <div class="panel panel-success" id="panelBody">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Room Details</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-body" style="height: 800px;">
                     <div class="list-group scroll-area" id="userList" style="height: 100%">
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </nav>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="click" id="launchButton" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body" style="height:220px; margin-top:300px;">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
      </button>
    </form>
</body>
```